# How to auto format one extra space around AND (&&) in VSCode?

Tags: javascript, typescript, if-statement, visual-studio-code, autoformatting

Let's say there is an if statement like this:

```
if( a && b )
    c();
```

Is there a way to auto-format it to having extra spaces around AND (`&&`) / OR (`||`) operators using VSCode's default formatter (`editor.formatOnSave`)?

```
if( a  &&  b )
    c();
```

Most formatting settings I found, except for this one.

Comment: In configuration terms, you'll probably want a space before _and_ after `a` and `b` and `&&`.

Comment: btw, it looks like that `if` is a function ...

Comment: Can you use Prettier as well or you are looking for pure VSCode solution?

Comment: @mandy8055, you could give me a prettier solution, but I'm looking for a pure VSCode solution as this is the only formatting I'm missing so far

Comment: @Z0q I only know the `"spaceAroundLogicalOperators": true` prettier setting, not sure if such an advanced formatting setting is available in the native formatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your own "formatter on save" command.  The following will run **on save** only.

You will need an extension I wrote that enables you to specify a find and replace in a setting and then designate that to run on save.  The extension is [Find and Transform](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.find-and-transform).  After installing the extension, make these settings (in your `settings.json`):

```json
 "findInCurrentFile": {

   "AddSpaceAround&&and||": {                   // whatever name you want
     "title": "add a space around && and ||",
     "find": "(?<=[^\\s]\\s)(&&|\\|\\|)(?=\\s[^\\s])",
     "replace": " $1 ",
     "isRegex": true
   }
 },


"[javascript][typescript]": {         // will only run on these files

  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": [
    "source.AddSpaceAround&&and||"    // run this command (from above) on save
  ]
}
```

This `find` `(?<=[^\\s]\\s)(&&|\\|\\|)(?=\\s[^\\s])` will get those `&&` or `||` that are surrounded by **one** space only - so you don't have to worry about it continually adding a space around those operators when there are already two spaces there.

Here is a demo:

[image: demo of wrapping operators with two spaces on save]

Note: this will not format as you type (there is probably no formatter that will make sure there are 2 spaces around an operator).  But the above works on save which is pretty neat.

Note: you can also run the command you created, here called `AddSpaceAround&&and||` at any time from the Command Palette or a keybinding.  Lots more info in the README's.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This looks quite exciting! Is there a way to clear the selections after replacing?

Comment: Found it by experimenting a bit using `preserveSelections` and setting it to `true` in your configuration

Comment: This is amazing, it allows me to add my own customizations and I enjoy it a lot. I updated the regex to this `(?<=\\(.*)(\\s*)(&&|\\|\\|)(\\s*)(?=.*\\))`, using replace `  $2  `

Comment: I also added `"preCommands": "editor.action.formatDocument",` to use apply formatting elsewhere when a match is found

Comment: You can also clear the selections with a `cancelSelection` postCommand but you probably want the `preserveSelections` option.

Comment: Thank you. One thing I noted is that the `preserveSelections` setting sometimes scrolls the view back to the cursor position if the view was scrolled up / down away from it

Comment: @Z0q I can't reproduce the scrolling/revealing action.  Can you post an issue at the repo https://github.com/ArturoDent/find-and-transform/issues with the settings you are using.  Thanks.

Comment: Issue created: https://github.com/ArturoDent/find-and-transform/issues/26

Answer (score 0):

VS Code's default JavaScript and TypeScript formatter come from TypeScript. The closest thing to what you want that I'm aware of that providing is `javascript.format.insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators` and `typescript.format.insertSpaceBeforeAndAfterBinaryOperators`. But I'm pretty sure that only makes one space and not two.

If you want something relatively vanilla, you could use search and replace as a workaround. Use the search view's replace feature, turn on regex mode, put `\s*(&&|\|\|)\s*` in the search field, and put  `$1`  in the replace field, and click the triple dots to open up the extra menu and put `*.ts,*.js` in the "files to include" field.

Answer (score 0):

So use the [Prittier](https://prettier.io/) extension. It will be easy for you. And also you can configure it from the VS Code setting.json according to the languages.

Comment: ... use the prettier extension how? what configuration options should the asker use and what should they set them to? where do they put those configuration details?

Comment: @Tiran And Prettier is opinionated, which is why I decided not to use it